# Como ajustar o alinhamento de uma <th>?

Tags: html, css

Eu gostaria de saber como eu faço para ajustar o alinhamento de um Table Heading `<th>`? Não sei se é possível fazer este procedimento assim como é feito para as `<tr>` ou `<td>`. Eu quero poder fazer isso para alinhar o conteúdo de cada célula da minha tabela com o texto do `<th>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dá pra alinhar com CSS e mais nada, olha:

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

th, td{
  width: 100px;
}

th{
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Experimente trocar o `.text-align` e ver como ele muda